# Deleted database still shows in database list in PostgreSQL SQLmanager

Tags: sql-manager

Using PostgreSQL 9.4.12, I created a new database called new_db and before adding any table or any other object to it and probably before registering it (I don't remember if I've registered or not), I dropped it. Now, it still shows in database list in SQLmanager:

[image]

and when I attempt to drop it via following query:

```
drop database new_db;
```

it says:

```
database doesn't exist
```

But when I open 'database registration manager', it lists 'new_db' and shows the register check box as marked:
[image]

and when I try to remove the mark and apply the changes it displays an error that isn't relevant to the 'new_db' database.

[image]

Following query also results 0 rows:

```
select oid, * from pg_database where datname like
   'new_db';
```

How can I remove the database from the list in SQLmanager?

Comment: did you try right click on new_db and "unregister database"?..

Comment: After restarting the machine I right clicked on the DB, unregistered it, and it worked. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Manager creates new_db (asdefault anme) on first connection. After that it registers it. If you just drop database and don't unregister it the "alias" remains. You have to right click on new_db and "unregister database"